# ng component not useful

Tags: javascript, angular

I was learning the ng-content. Why need to use it when we can easily write like this

**with ng-content**

menu.component.html

```
<div>

    <app-message> <h1>Laptop</h1></app-message>
</div>
```

message.component.html

```
<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
        <p>something text to be display</p>
        <button > Submit</button>
</div>
```

**without ng-content**

menu.component.html

```
<div>
    <h1>Laptop</h1>
    <app-message> </app-message>
</div>
```

message.component.html

```
<div>
        <p>something text to be display</p>
        <button > Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you want to display some content in the middle of your component template?

Answer (score 0):

Using `<ng-content>` allows you to create flexible reusable components.

For example, a custom app-modal component:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-title">
    {{title}}
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is very powerful, and only the start of what you can achieve with `<ng-content>`

A core prinpiple of software engineering is code reuse (DRY). With this we can bundle all of the logic relating to a component into one component, and inject the content into it.

This is like asking the question

> Why not just declare your CSS styles inline instead of in CSS classes?

It is possible, but unmaintainable, and we have evolved beyond that.

Your example is fairly trivial, but it is still useful if you wanted to change style or behaviour based on some injected logic.

Answer (score 0):

There exist some situations when is necessary, maybe no in simple cases but when the app grows up and you have to insert a custom component inside another is very usefully

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your own example, without using `ng-content`, the parent component suddenly is partially responsible for the child's layout. It'll get messy real quick, the quicker the more complex the layout gets.

Answer (score 0):

It's useful for displaying components inside of other components, so the components can be reusable. For example, if you want to display some text on a few pages, you call the component with the text inside of the other components that you want the text to be displayed on. It could also be useful for showing different information but styled in the same format. E.g.

if your ng-content already has the information this is an example of how it would be used:

menu.component.html

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

message.component.html

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

This is good because you can copy and paste the exact component into another one without having to rewrite the code

If your ng-content is looking for a data source for information to pass into it

```
<ng-content [data]='data'></ng-content>
```

This is good because you can recreate the component inside of another component but with different data inside of it.

If you've ever used react, you pass data into it in a similar way here as you would with react props, but instead of props in angular, it will be an @input field. Here is some example code

test.component.html

```
<ng-content [data]='THIS IS THE DATA'></ng-content>
```

This is the actual component, as you can see, it is looking for a data source

ng-content.component.html

```
<p>The data we are looking for is {{data}} </p>
```

ng-content.component.ts - this says that when the component is called, it is looking for an input called 'data' and the type has to be a string

```
@Input() data: string;
```

We would then see the test.component.html displayed like this:

The data we are looking for is THIS IS THE DATA